# how to deal with sunspot when distributed deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, solr, sunspot

Now I have a rails application to deploy.

I use two app servers and a dababase server.

the two app servers run the same code to load balancing.

I use sunspot(solr) do fulltext search. I want to keep the search result no different no mater which app server I was accessing.

**question 1:**

where should I run the solr process? Each App a solr OR only run the solr on datatbase server?

**question 2:**

where to store the index?

give me some advise OR some link, THX.